# FCM demo cannot get token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a project on Firebase console. I had register the package on the Firebase console, But I can`t get any token from the log even hit the LOG TOKEN button in the app.

Then I try to send message with Firebase console and set to target to my app package name.I didn't get any incoming message from the log.

[image]

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = "HelloJni";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
     if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
    // [END handle_data_extras]

    Button subscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);
    subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg + ",  " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

RegistrationIntentService.java

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.i(TAG, "FCM Registration Token: " + token);
}
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e(TAG, "oncreate.........");
}

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
// [START refresh_token]
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onTokenRefresh  call...");
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
// [END refresh_token]

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "  sendRegistrationToServer  Refreshed token: " + token);
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e(TAG, "oncreate..........");
}

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.example.hellojni.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="RegistrationIntentService" ></service>
</application>
```

[image]

`OnCreate()` for MyFirebaseInstanceIDService and MyFirebaseMessagingService was not called, and the token returns null.

The log:

```
02-20 18:05:28.273 23322-23322 W/InstanceID/Rpc: Failed to resolve REGISTER intent, falling back

02-20 18:05:28.273 23322-23322 W/InstanceID/Rpc: Both Google Play Services and legacy GSF package are missing

02-20 18:05:28.273 23322-23322 W/InstanceID/Rpc: Failed to resolve REGISTER intent, falling back

02-20 18:05:28.273 23322-23322 W/InstanceID/Rpc: Both Google Play Services and legacy GSF package are missing

02-20 18:05:28.273 23322-23322 D/HelloJni: Subscribed to news topic,  null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device or emulator you are testing on does not have Google Play Services or the Google Service Framework (GSF) installed.  Most of the Firebase APIs use the capabilities of Google Play Services and will not run if it is not present on the device.

Answer (score 0):

put this at last after dependency in your app level gradle.`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

and put this into your project level gradle.`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

make sure you have puted google-service.json in app module.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add .

```
              apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in last line in your gradle file and .

```
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

in your project level file  . IntentService service class will called only ones when your app intralled  so delete app every time and  and intrall every time when you want to generate tocken

Answer (score 0):

I see the reason. I run the app with Android phone made in China, and these phones has no google play service and store.